# Project Reactor: downstream is slow

Tags: java, reactive-programming, project-reactor

For my understanding, the rest of the downstream needs to be processed on a thread from the thread-pool (and I set it to 1024)

Here's my code.

```
Flux<String> ips =
        Flux.fromIterable(items).map(Item::getIp);
ips
        .publishOn(Schedulers.fromExecutor(Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1024)))
        .map(ip -> {
            try {
                Request request = new Request.Builder().url("https://" + ip + ":443").build();
                Response response = okHttpClient.newCall(request).execute();
                return response.code();
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }

            return -1;
        })
        .subscribe(System.out::println);
```

For some reason, this code is very slow in comparison to:

```
appRules
        .stream()
        .parallel()
        .map(Item::getIp)
        .forEach(ip -> {
            try {
                Request request = new Request.Builder().url("https://" + ip + ":443").build();
                Response response = okHttpClient.newCall(request).execute();
                System.out.println(response.code());
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }

            System.out.println(-1);
        });
```

Why? What's the correct way to process a stream of items, concurrently, when you're bounded by IO? (and not CPU)

Comment: Considering that parallel streams are for CPU bound operations, that's a surprising outcome. The example code you provided is not really useful in its current form. Could you attach some logs maybe where we can see thread names and time stamps? It would help to understand what's going on. It would also be interesting to know how much latency and concurrency you deal with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for the slower execution is that Reactor pipeline execution is single-threaded by default. So when you use `Flux.publishOn` operator you just say that you want this part of the pipeline executed on a thread from the given thread pool but it will NOT execute each item on a separate thread concurrently.

One option to achieve concurrency is to use [parallel Flux](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html#parallel--), which creates so called rails where data can flow parallelly, but it is mostly used for CPU-bound operations.

The better option is to wrap the blocking code inside a Mono and delegate it to a dedicated thread pool, similar to what you have done, only this time each task will get its own thread:

```java
private static void reactorProcess()
{
    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1024);

    Flux.range(1, 1024)
        .flatMap(a -> Mono.fromRunnable(() -> simulateHttpCall())
                          .subscribeOn(Schedulers.fromExecutor(executor)))
        .blockLast();

    executor.shutdown();
}

private static void simulateHttpCall()
{
    try
    {
        Thread.sleep(100);
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + ": " + ZonedDateTime.now());
    } catch (InterruptedException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I would also note that Java parallel stream is not a viable alternative for this kind of processing. It uses [ForkJoinPool](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ForkJoinPool.html) by default which is also intended for CPU-bound operations and uses only as many threads as many CPU cores you have in your machine.

Other than that, if you'd like to leverage the full power of reactive programming you should consider using a HTTP client which supports non-blocking IO, like [WebClient](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/reactive/function/client/WebClient.html) from Spring. By using a non-blocking HTTP client you don't need to worry about defining thread pools anymore, since no thread will be blocked and a fixed, small number of threads will be able to serve thousands of concurrent requests.

Comment: thanks a lot for the detailed answer! I think I'll try first the WebClient but awesome to learn how to do it directly.